# Collection framework removalCheck

Tags: java, collections, instanceof

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) 
{
    Object element = iterator.next();
    if (removalCheck(element)) 
    {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

I have some collection framework related program which I am trying to comprehend. My problem is what is that `removalCheck` doing over there.Is it a method? If so what is its class hierarchy. Or is it an operator similar to `instanceof` or anything other than those mentioned.
I tried searching about that but couldn't get a conclusive answer.

Comment: Yes. It's a method (Not part of the API).

Comment: If its a method it must be part of some class right.

Comment: Probably it's a helper method, might be written in the *same* class you're viewing.

Comment: Nope its directly used in that iterator loop and i also checked the api of iterator interface but api doesnt have any such method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the code you posted is syntactically valid and compiles without errors, it's a helper method, either in the class you're viewing or in a class extended by the class you are viewing.

Comment: http://www.java4all.in/java/collectionapi3.php....look at the code return in that link...can you infer anything?

Comment: That page is a general example of something you could do with a collection.  It doesn't imply an actual concrete implementation of a `removalCheck` method.